# Display the same piece of javascript script in bootstrap columns that are col-sm6

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript script with a function called fuctionone() that displays a graph. I call this script below in a p tag so when 'HERE' is clicked the graph is displayed below each header.

```
<svg width="480" height="250">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="card-title">Example one</h3>

                <p><a href="#" onclick="functionone()"> HERE </a> </p>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="card-title">Example two</h3>

                <p><a href="#" onclick="functionone()"> HERE </a> </p>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </svg>
```

However I want to display the same graph in each column but when I click the HERE link above only one graph is displayed under Example one when I want two graphs displayed for each.

One under Example one and one under Example two.

Is the `<svg>` tag messing this up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

`functionOne` has no idea where it's being called from if I had to guess. Next time I'd recommend posting your javascript for clarity. Pass the element to your javascript function, then manipulate the DOM.
`functionOne(this)`